# Python BeautifulSoup to Extract Image tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract image links from imdb webpage.

for example, `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1` has image element `<img alt="Avatar Poster" title="Avatar Poster" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg">`

Below is the code I am using and not getting the image url link.

row[17], which is the link I am trying to use, in my code can be found under

```
https://www.kaggle.com/carolzhangdc/imdb-5000-movie-dataset
```

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

with open('movie_metadata.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
            line_count += 1
        else:
            imdb_link = row[17]
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(imdb_link).read(), features="html.parser")
            link = soup.find(itemprop="img")
            print('\t{} =====> {} =====> {} ====> {}.'.format(row[-1], row[11], row[17], link["src"]))
            line_count += 1
```

I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` when running the code

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks a lot!

Comment: do you get error or what? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should search `find('img')` because `img` is tag name, not its property.

Comment: @furas thanks! I updated my code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: put FULL error message - not only last line. Error shows in which line is problem. Maybe your problem is in different place then you descirbe.

Comment: BTW: if you use `soup.find(itemprop="img")` then it will not find `<img>` (because ` `img` in `<img>` is not property but tag name) and `link` will have value `None` (simply check `print(link)`) and `link['src']` will mean `None['src']` so you get error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: as you get in answer below - you have to use `find('img')` instead of `find(itemprop="img")` - but also it is good to check `if link:` or `if link is not None:` before you use `link['src']`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simplify your code by using requests with Beautiful Soup so that you can debug it in a more feasible way:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
soup.find('img', {'title': 'Avatar Poster'}).get('src')
```

Comment: That works but in my for loop I am trying to get every movie in my csv file. I just have urls for the movie pages

Comment: In such IO operations, a good practice is to get all the content that you want to put in the file first

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, I've forgotten to add a `GET` call via `requests`